# Filter MYSQL table for with maximum dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date, where-clause

I would like to filter my table and select all the lines where the date is the latest date in the column called 'date'

If possible I would like to use the 'where' function.

Note I have many rows with the same date. e.g I have a table with all days sales by product, but I want to see only the latest days sales.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the  [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question with the details needed to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query to get the whole list of records where date is the latest one:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE date=(SELECT MAX(date) 
            FROM `table`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2);
```

If you wanted the latest day *per product*, then you would use a correlated subquery.

```
select t.*
from t
where date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.product = t.product);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use exists logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.date > t1.date);
```

On MySQL 8+, I like using `RANK` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

You could also use Gordon's subquery approach for a third option.